# Magento 1 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I've my magento 1 installed since 5 months and I never had a problem, all was working fine. Today with no reason I can't access to my installation, frontend and backend made the same error ad stop the execution.

This is the error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:95:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)";i:1;s:2994:"
#0 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1357): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1389): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(619): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/xp1qh8ju/public_html/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to various reasons. The first thing you have to do is to restart your MySQL server. The command may depend on the Linux distribution you're using, but it's something like:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

So, why it could happen:
- Your MySQL died for various reason (out-of-memory, bug...)
- You've run out of connections (reached max-connections limit defined in my.cnf)